# Repeating steps with different values in BDD test case

Tags: bdd, specflow, feature-file

I am new to BDD specflow.
I have to write a scenario wherein after I capture an image, i have to select a value for each defined attribute for that image from a selection list

For Eg:

```
    |Body Part  |Location  |Group  |
    |   Leg     |   Left   | Skin  |
    |   Hand    |   Upper  | Burn  |
    |   Arm     |   Right  | Ulcer |
```

I need a way in which i can select a different value for each attribute, every time.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Scenario Outline](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-Outlines);

> Scenario outlines allow us to more concisely express these examples through the use of a template with placeholders, using Scenario Outline, Examples with tables and < > delimited parameters.

`Specflow` takes each line in the `Example` table and create from the line a scenario to execute.